# How to increase disk storage in Azure Cloud Service classic

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

In a old project, we still use Cloud Services (classic) where I want to increase the size of the **Local Disk F**. Right now the disk is 2 GB in size and I don't find any way to increase it.

I have not found a corresponding setting in the ServiceDefinition.csdef file or the ServiceConfig.cscfg file.

Is this even possible?
[image]

[image: {]

Comment: Are you looking to increase the size of local storage?

Comment: @GauravMantri Hi Gaurav, I want to increase the size of a local drive that gets created automatically with the Cloud Service deployment. The content of the folder is the approot, siteroot and such things - I added a screenshot of the drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: I realized you were talking about the approot drive (E/F drive) and not the temp disk

The approot drive (E/F drive) is fixed and cannot be modified.  For more information and limitations on this drive see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-configuration-and-management-faq#why-does-the-drive-on-my-cloud-service-vm-show-very-little-free-disk-space-.

> The %approot% drive size is calculated as <size of .cspkg + max
> journal size + a margin of free space>, or 1.5 GB, whichever is
> larger. The size of your VM has no bearing on this calculation. (The
> VM size only affects the size of the temporary C: drive.)
>
> It is unsupported to write to the %approot% drive. If you are writing
> to the Azure VM, you must do so in a temporary LocalStorage resource
> (or other option, such as Blob storage, Azure Files, etc.). So the
> amount of free space on the %approot% folder is not meaningful. If you
> are not sure if your application is writing to the %approot% drive,
> you can always let your service run for a few days and then compare
> the "before" and "after" sizes.
>
> Azure will not write anything to the %approot% drive. Once the VHD is
> created from your .cspkg and mounted into the Azure VM, the only thing
> that might write to this drive is your application.

original answer regarding temp disk size:

The local disk size in a Cloud Service VM is controlled by the VM size, which you define in your .csdef file:

```
<WorkerRole name="Worker1" vmsize="Standard_D2">
...
</WorkerRole>
```

For the different size options, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-sizes-specs

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was already afraid that the drive could not be enlarged... BR